# Allow databases start with specific name

Tags: postgresql, pg-hba.conf

In PostgreSQL sometimes we replace a database, we rename the old when a create a new one, example:

- Database: test
- Rename database to: test-04-04 (date)
- Create a newdatabase: test

Now we have a lot of databases named : test-"date" and its becoming hard to add database at pg_hba every time, is there a way to allow all database start with `test` like `test*` ?

Comment: Why no simply allow access to all databases through `pg_hba.conf` but remove the connect privilege through SQL for the users and databases in question?